# ODBC error in php?

Tags: php, odbc, azure-sql-database, unixodbc

Hi I was wondering what the following error means and why am I getting it?

`[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`

My arguements for `odbc_conntect()` - `"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:database.windows.net;Database=someDB;Encrypt=yes;", 'user@database', 'passwd'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it was not working is that I did not have the correct driver installed or `unixODBC` with a `dsn` setup.

Answer (score 0):

you are running this prog on UNIX and the string is windows based

Comment: thx for the answer. I don't know much about microsoft based SQL databases or ODBC. So what would be a UNIX formatted string?

Comment: check this link http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html